# nHibernate 3 - Left Join re-Linq solution

Tags: linq, nhibernate, left-join

I am trying to to run this Linq query below with nHibernate 3.

```
var items = from c in session.Query<tbla>()
       join t in session.Query<tblb>() on c.Id equals t.SomeId into t1 // use left join on trades.
       from t2 in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {item = c, desc = t2.Description};
```

This is the stock way to perform a left join in linq to my knowledge. However it's giving me an unsupported exception message. How can I achieve a basic left join without resorting back to HQL? This seems somewhat silly that an ORM as prevalent as nHibernate cannot support something as pedestrian as a left join.

[edit]

I've put the real answer to my own question below.

Comment: I'm lost. Where are the equivalents for "on c.Id equals t.SomeId into t1" and "new {item = c, desc = t2.Description}" in the example? Could you extend the example and/or comments?

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. Why don't you submit your own answer? I would vote for it.

Comment: Good call i've moved my edit to an answer. The join magic happens in the `SelectList` clause of that expression. Hopefully that helps. The second query is not an exact match logic wise for the first query so no apple to apple comparison there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further research on this; this is possible (although not obvious) to achieve in a strongly typed fashion using [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover). The trick is to use outer Query alias variables in conjunction with WithAlias, and TransformUsing. Here is an example that does left join with filtering and sorting.

```
// Query alias variables 
entityTypeA anchorType = null;
entityTypeB joinedType = null;

var items = session.Query<entityTypeA>( ()=>anchorType )
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => anchorType.FieldName, () => joinedType)
            .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(e => e.FieldD).In(myFilterList)
            // bind property mappings using WithAlias
            .SelectList(list => list
                        .Select(e => e.FieldNameA).WithAlias( ()=> anchorType.FieldNameA )
                        .Select(e => e.FieldNameB).WithAlias( ()=> anchorType.FieldNameB )
                        )
           .OrderBy(e => joinedType.FieldNameC).Desc
           .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<entityTypeA>()) // transform result to desired type.
           .List<entityTypeA>();
```

Comment: There is one issue with that approach: your retrieved entity actually behaves like a DTO (i.e. it's not tracked)

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported yet. HQL is your only choice at the moment.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid of that. Is there perhaps another alternative non-hql way of doing this i.e. subquery w/ where outer clause etc?