# Left join in linq in NHibernate 3.2

Tags: linq, nhibernate, left-join

Is it possible to implement left join in linq in NHibernate 3.2 ?

I want to achive a linq query similar to this sql query:

```
select v.*, cp.EffectiveStart
from Visits v
join VisitServices vs on v.Id = vs.VisitId
left join CarePlans cp on cp.Id = vs.CarePlanId
```

I have written such linq query:

```
var c = (from v in EntitiesRepository
                     join vs in _visitServiceRepository on v.Id equals vs.Visit.Id
                     join cp in _carePlanRepository on vs.CarePlan.Id equals cp.Id into pp                     
                     from pl in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { Visit = v, EffectiveStart = pl.EffectiveStart}).ToList();
```

But I got this exception

> The method or operation is not implemented.

**Answer**:
I was able to fix the issue using navigation property:

```
    var c = (from v in EntitiesRepository
             join vs in _visitServiceRepository on v.Id equals vs.Visit.Id
             select new { Visit = v, EffectiveStart = vs.CarePlan == null ? null : (DateTime?)vs.CarePlan.EffectiveStart}).ToList();
```

Comment: As of NH 3.1 this was not supported. The exception indicates that this hasn't changed in NH 3.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nHibernate 3 - Left Join re-Linq solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708029/nhibernate-3-left-join-re-linq-solution)

Answer (score 4):

Outer joins are currently only supported over navigation properties. Example:

```
from child in parent.Children.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

edit: Sorry, seems like that was not in 3.2. Can't you update?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue using navigation property:

```
    var c = (from v in EntitiesRepository
             join vs in _visitServiceRepository on v.Id equals vs.Visit.Id
             select new { Visit = v, EffectiveStart = vs.CarePlan == null ? null : (DateTime?)vs.CarePlan.EffectiveStart}).ToList();
```